# Thymeleaf authorization with Spring Security doesn't work

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I'm using Spring Security in my Spring Boot app and it seems that Thymeleaf authorization doesn't work properly.

I have the Thymeleaf template with the following code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
        <h2 style="color:green">User is Logged In</h2>
        <p sec:authentication="principal.username">username</p>
    </div>

    <div class="row" sec:authorize="!isAuthenticated()">
        <h2 style="color:red">User is Logged Out</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="row" sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_SUPERUSER')">
        <h2>This will only be displayed if authenticated user has role ROLE_SUPERUSER.</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="row" sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
        <h2>This will only be displayed if authenticated user has role ROLE_ADMIN.</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="row" sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">
        <h2>This will only be displayed if authenticated user has role ROLE_USER.</h2>
    </div>

    <div th:if="${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''ROLE_ADMIN'')')}">
        This will only be displayed if authenticated user has role ROLE_ADMIN.
    </div>

    <div th:if="${#authorization.expr('hasRole(''ROLE_ADMIN'')')}">
        This will only be displayed if authenticated user has role ROLE_ADMIN.
    </div>
</div>
```

*Examples are taken from: https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity*

However the only content that is shown is `sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()"` and `sec:authorize="!isAuthenticated()"` and the authorization is always ignored, regardless of the user's role.

My thymeleaf configuration is:

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig {

    @Bean
    public TemplateResolver defaultTemplateResolver() {
        TemplateResolver resolver = new TemplateResolver();
        resolver.setResourceResolver(thymeleafResourceResolver());
        resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        resolver.setCacheable(true);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceResourceResolver thymeleafResourceResolver() {
        return new SpringResourceResourceResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(TemplateResolver templateResolver) {
        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
        engine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
        engine.addDialect(new LayoutDialect());
        return engine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver(SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine);
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        resolver.setContentType("text/html");
        resolver.setOrder(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE - 5);
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

And I use the following dependency for [`thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf.extras/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4/2.1.3.RELEASE):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Version `3.0.2.RELEASE` didn't work at all, and `sec` namespace was always ignored by Thymeleaf.
My Spring Boot version is `1.5.2.RELEASE`.

What could be the reason?

**UPDATE.** The `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method in `SecurityConfig` looks as:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/h2-console").disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/webjars/**", "/static/**", "/images/**", "/**/favicon.ico").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/heat/**", "/power/**", "/water/**").permitAll()

            // start allowing h2-console
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll();
            http.csrf().disable();
            http.headers().frameOptions().disable()
            // end allowing h2-console

            .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/info").permitAll()
            .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/users/**").authenticated()
            .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/users/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "SUPERUSER")

            .and().formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
            .and()
                    .logout()
                    .permitAll()
                    .deleteCookies("remove")
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)

            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access_denied");
}
```

and the mapping from the `IndexController` is pretty simple, it just returns the `login` template:

```
@RequestMapping("/login")
public String loginForm() {
    return "login";
}
```

Comment: As I know role is just an authority with a special `ROLE_` prefix. My roles doesn't have this prefix, they're just `USER`, `ADMIN` and so on: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpBA1.png

Comment: I prefix my roles with `ROLE_` when I use `hasRole`, but the role names themselves in the table go without this prefix.

Comment: @DimaSan: That's the point. If you use `hasRole`, you have to use the prefix in your database. But you can configure a different prefix or use `hasAuthority` (as in your answer).

Comment: Yes you are right, now I can confirm that it works as you described. So what is the best practice to have role names with or without `ROLE_` prefix?

Comment: I use only role names with prefix, because I don't like too much customized configurations. I try to use the defaults as far as possible. But Spring developers would say, it is your decision both is possible.

Answer (score 12):

**Version note:** Below does not work in Thymeleaf 3.1+ due to new security restrictions.

An alternative way of solving the task is to use this syntax to check role:

```html
<div class="row" th:if="${#request.isUserInRole('SUPERUSER')}">
    <h2>This will only be displayed if authenticated user has role ROLE_SUPERUSER.</h2>
</div>
```

It does not use the `sec` namespace and actually the thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4 dependency is not needed at all to use this.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but the result is the same, Thymeleaf completely ignoring user's role. Btw the right is `th:if="${#httpServletRequest.isUserInRole('SUPERUSER')}"`.

Comment: @DimaSan hmmm, may be a mismatch between versions.

Comment: Do you mean Thymelaf version? I use `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` dependency and Thymeleaf version there is 2.1.5.RELEASE.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I could not get sec:authorize to work no matter what I tried.  It always returned true.  You answer perfectly though.

Comment: this actually worked for me on my spring mvc and spring security 4.2.3

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of tries with different configurations I found a workaround. In this case `sec:authorize="hasAuthority('ADMIN')"` attribute works:

```
<div class="row" sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
        <h2>User Has Role Admin</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" sec:authorize="hasAuthority('ADMIN')">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
        <h2>User Has Authority Admin</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

and `User Has Authority Admin` header renders on the page.

Still have no idea why `sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"` attribute doesn't work, as it is suggested as an example on the `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity` GitHub page:
https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity#using-the-attributes

Hope this could help someone, although the question is still open.

Answer (score 1):

Things to try:

1) Annotate your configuration with `@EnableWebMvc`.

2) Replace `ROLE_ADMIN` with just `ADMIN` (and the others correspondingly too).

3) In your controller, print this to see your current roles:

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

Set<String> roles = authentication.getAuthorities().stream()
     .map(r -> r.getAuthority()).collect(Collectors.toSet());

System.out.println(roles);
```

If that doesn't work for you, perhaps try `getUserPrincipal()` from `HttpServletRequest`.

**Short of that:**

I am including my MVC config so that you can try the latest Thymeleaf and Spring Security versions.  There are some extra configurations in there, so you can remove what's not relevant to your project.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configuration) {

        configuration.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {

        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public TemplateEngine templateEngine() {

        Set<ITemplateResolver> templateResolvers = new LinkedHashSet<>(1);
        templateResolvers.add(webTemplateResolver());

        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolvers(templateResolvers);
        Set<IDialect> dialects = new LinkedHashSet<>(2);
        dialects.add(new SpringSecurityDialect());
        dialects.add(new Java8TimeDialect());
        templateEngine.setAdditionalDialects(dialects);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ITemplateResolver webTemplateResolver() {

        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/thymeleaf/");
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setCacheable(false);
        resolver.setOrder(2);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver tilesViewResolver() {

        UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(TilesView.class);
        viewResolver.setOrder(0);
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {

        TilesConfigurer configurer = new TilesConfigurer();
        configurer.setDefinitions("/WEB-INF/**/views.xml");
        return configurer;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {

        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addViewController("/403");
        registry.addViewController("/404");
        registry.addViewController("/about");
        //edited for brevity
    }

    @Bean
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {

        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        source.setBasename("classpath:messages");
        source.setDefaultEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        return source;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {

        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
        registry.addInterceptor(themeChangeInterceptor());
        registry.addInterceptor(deviceResolverHandlerInterceptor());
        super.addInterceptors(registry);
    }

    @Bean
    public HandlerInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {

        LocaleChangeInterceptor interceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        interceptor.setParamName("lang");
        return interceptor;
    }

    @Bean
    public HandlerInterceptor themeChangeInterceptor() {

        ThemeChangeInterceptor interceptor = new ThemeChangeInterceptor();
        interceptor.setParamName("theme");
        return interceptor;
    }

    @Bean
    public ResourceBundleThemeSource themeSource() {

        ResourceBundleThemeSource themeSource = new ResourceBundleThemeSource();
        themeSource.setBasenamePrefix("theme-");
        return themeSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistedThemeResolver themeResolver() {

        PersistedThemeResolver resolver = new PersistedThemeResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultThemeName("default");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public HandlerInterceptor deviceResolverHandlerInterceptor() {

        return new DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor();
    }

    @Bean
    public CookieLocaleResolver localeResolver() {

        CookieLocaleResolver resolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
        return resolver;
    }

    //removed custom bean declaration

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {

        argumentResolvers.add(new ServletWebArgumentResolverAdapter(new DeviceWebArgumentResolver()));
        super.addArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
    }

    @Bean
    public Executor taskExecutor() {

        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(100);
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

Working pom excerpt:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javassist</groupId>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, with your `WebMvcConfig` configuration the behavior is the same: authorities works with `antMatchers` (so that ADMIN can access `.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/users/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "SUPERUSER")` page, configured in `SpringSecurityConfig`) but they are not rendered in the Thymeleaf template with `sec:authorize` tag.
Also roles are printed from the controller as I expect, and admin has `USER` and `ADMIN` roles. That must be something wrong with thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4.
Anyway thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Ok, total guess but I updated my question with a snippet from my POM.  I haven't done the minor upgrade yet on Spring Security, but that combination works for me without Boot.  This is all assuming the `sec` namespace is defined at the top of the HTML file of course.